# Function with default argument doesn't compile with VC++, but does with g++ and clang

Tags: c++, templates

I've searched this site and cannot find a solution to my problem.  I have reduced my sample code down as much as I think I can while still retaining the relevant error.  I am left with the following two files:

test.hpp

```
namespace models {

template<typename FloatingPoint>
class ellipsoid {
  public:
    explicit ellipsoid(FloatingPoint = 6378137.0);
  private:
    FloatingPoint a_;
};

template<typename FloatingPoint>
ellipsoid<FloatingPoint>::ellipsoid(FloatingPoint a) : a_(a) {}

}  // End namespace models


// Function declaration
template<typename FloatingPoint>
FloatingPoint compute(FloatingPoint,
                      const models::ellipsoid<FloatingPoint>& =
                          models::ellipsoid<FloatingPoint>());

// Function definition
template<typename FloatingPoint>
FloatingPoint compute(FloatingPoint x,
                      const models::ellipsoid<FloatingPoint>& model) {

    return 3.14;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"

int main() {
    compute(10.0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above code using VC++ 2017, I get the following error:

```
error C2512: 'models::ellipsoid<FloatingPoint>': no appropriate default constructor available
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Both clang and g++ compile this without a problem.  Also, if I remove the `ellipsoid` class from the namespace `models`, and remove the `models::` invocations in the `compute` function, it then compiles fine using VC++.  Is this a bug within the VC++ compiler, or have I got a bug in my code?

Comment: _(I like the way the compiler gives two possible error causes and lets you guess which it actually encountered - makes every error a guessing game, that's definitely what I look for in a production tool)_

Comment: Workaround: `explicit ellipsoid(FloatingPoint);` then `explicit ellipsoid():ellipsoid(6378137.0){}`.  This should behave the same in gcc and clang, and may make msvc happy.

Comment: @Yakk, as I was trying to type an answer for this, I realized there seem to be a disagreement between [dcl.fct.default/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct.default-5) saying *copy initialization* and [class.conv.ctor/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#2) saying *direct initialization*. But in the [examples](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#2) of *explicit ctors*, I see a *copy initialization* syntax, (precisely, `Z a3 = Z(1);`) are there some overlap?

Comment: @whiz no clue, which is why I posted a workaround and not an answer.

Comment: Definitely a bug, not a deliberate incompatibility with standard C++, this time. The MSDN documentation for VS15 says, “Default constructors can be called with no arguments. However, you can declare a default constructor with an argument list, provided all arguments have defaults.” (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in VC++, which was fixed in Visual Studio 2019 since compiler version 19.23. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a5TxPa8ac